# Error triggering a matrix tests when I run my Espresso tests using Test Lab for Android

Tags: firebase, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

When I run my Espresso tests from Android Studio 2.2.1 using Test Lab for Android I get the following error message:

> Exception while triggering a matrix execution. 429 Too Many Requests.

I managed to run several tests on remote devices, but then they start failing with this error message. Firebase console shows nothing.

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the HTTP Status returned when a project that is on the Flame or Spark tier has used too much of its quota.

Projects on the Spark and Flame tier can send up to 10 virtual device tests and 5 physical device tests per day (with each day beginning at midnight PDT). In addition, there is a maximum of 4 tests per test matrix for projects on these plans.

See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ for more.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem! Can you mark the answer as accepted or upvote it? That way the question will be marked as answered.

Comment: @MichaelLawrence I haven't ran a single test and I keep getting that error. Why is that?